# intellisense for previously declared variables and constants

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am using MSVS C++ Express 2008. Right now my intellisense only works for objects that have methods or arguments in a method. Is it possible to set it where it detects declared constants and varibles that are within scope. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work when you hover over a constant, or any variable for that matter.  It should show you the definition.  I'm not sure if there are any feature differences between the Express and "real" versions, but I don't believe so.

Some things to try:

1. Do a rebuild of the solution.
2. Restart VS.
3. There is a file in your solution root directory with an ".ncb" extension.  Delete it and restart VS.  This forces VS to rebuild the Intellisense database.

Intellisense is notoriously flakey...

Comment: I am working from a empty project. I only have 1 source file. which contains the main method. I dont know the proper term. but when I mean intellisense, I mean as in it auto detects variables and I can select it and it write out the rest of the word.